# Can Ethereum be used to tokenize bandwidth?

Tags: tokens, server-side, bandwith

Decentralizing internet bandwidth usage, by allowing blockchain users to act as server nodes using their desktop computers and be paid for it, would fix the problem of running massive server rooms where data must be centralized.

Why isn't Ethereum directed towards solving this problem, whereas **[Theta token](http://thetatoken.org)** does? (a separate blockchain that is no longer ERC20)

Wouldn't gas fees or their equivalent  be astronomically even more high for this sort of data-heavy use case where a blockchain is trying to decentralize bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't guarantee bandwidth. If I bought a token that gave me access to 100Mb/s stream of XYZ, what happens if that 100Mb/s rate is not available at the time of redemption?

Also, local consumer grade hardware will never outperform dedicated server farms. Theta's network can't rely on residential users either because most ISP AUPs already prohibit users from running servers or service like services.